# How to use $t(29/\sqrt{2})<0$ where $t(x)=x^2-41x+420$ to prove that $41/29<\sqrt{2}<42/29$??

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, approximation, quadratics

So I was investigating different ways to approximate $\sqrt{2}$.

Here's my latest:

$$Let:t(x)=x^2-41x+420$$

then the roots of $t(x)$ are $20$ and $21$.

I showed that then $t(x)=(x-20)(x-21)$ and know I have to show that $t\left(\frac{29}{\sqrt{2}}\right) \lt 0$.
I used the fact that I got from another question that $\frac{40}{29} \lt \sqrt{2}< \frac{42}{29}$ and using a table I proved that $t\left(\frac{29}{\sqrt{2}}\right) \lt 0$.

Now I need to conclude from $t\left(\frac{29}{\sqrt{2}}\right) \lt 0$ we have $\frac{41}{29} \lt \sqrt{2}< \frac{42}{29}$

But I don't know how to proceed!

Thank you so much!

Comment: @Tunococ I made an error, it is not $40/29<29/\sqrt{2}<42/29$ but $40/29<\sqrt{2}<42/29$

Comment: I made an error too. What I stated was wrong. What you stated is right, and it can be proved by squaring...

Comment: @Tunococ But we can't prove that $41/29<\sqrt{2}<42/29$ directly from our results on $t(29/\sqrt{2})$

Comment: I am not sure which is more "direct". Maybe I might understand better if you can tell me what "table" you used to prove $t(29/\sqrt 2) < 0$. (Did you use it just to conclude $20 < 29/\sqrt 2 < 21$?)

Comment: @Tunococ I used it to solve the inequality $t(x)<0$ and I've then found that $t(x)<0$ is equivalent to $x\in]20,21[$ and since $29/\sqrt{2}\in ]20,21[$ then $t(29/\sqrt{2})<0$.

Comment: My question is how you came to the conclusion that $29/\sqrt 2 \in {]}20, 21{[}$...

Comment: @Tunococ I assumed that $20<29/\sqrt{2}<21$. 
$$$$ How can we prove that $t(29/\sqrt{2})<0$ without this assumption?

Comment: It is a valid assumption as it can be proved, also by squaring.

Comment: @Tunococ So can we use the fact that $t(29/\sqrt{2})<0$ and $t(x)<0\iff x \in {]}20, 21{[}$ to prove that $\frac{41}{29} \lt \sqrt{2}< \frac{42}{29}$ ?

Comment: It looks as though you are finding good fractional approximations to $\sqrt 2$. There are better (more efficient) ways to do this by partial fractions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Squaring is the best method to prove the inequality. However, there is a detour, which involves squaring and nastier computation (and somewhat magical factorization), that may be what you're looking for.

Substitute $x = \frac{29}{\sqrt 2}$ in $t(x) = x^2 - 41x + 420$ to get
\begin{align}
t\left(\frac{29}{\sqrt 2}\right)
= \frac{29^2}{2} - 41 \cdot \frac{29}{\sqrt 2} + 420 & < 0 \\
29^2 + 42 \cdot 20 & < 41 \cdot 29 \cdot \sqrt 2 \\
\frac{41^2}{41 \cdot 29} & < \sqrt 2 \\
\frac{41}{29} & < \sqrt 2.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

If $(x-20)(x-21)\lt 0$ then you must have $20\lt x \lt 21$ and you can't prove anything stronger from this inequality.

So if $t\left(\frac {29}{\sqrt 2}\right)\lt 0$ you have $$20\lt\frac {29}{\sqrt 2}\lt 21$$ If you multiply this through by $\frac 2{29}$ you get: $$\frac{40}{29}\lt \sqrt 2\lt \frac {42}{29}$$

You can't do better than this without a different method.

Comment: So we can't derive $\frac{41}{29}<\sqrt{2}<\frac{42}{29}$ with just $(x-20)(x-21)<0$ and $t(29/\sqrt{2})<0$ ?